# Why beginPath method used in the paint application in Canvas?

Tags: canvas, rust, html5-canvas

This is a question regarding `Canvas` . This is an example paint app written in `rust` which compiles to `WebAssembly`. It uses canvas for drawing. It starts drawing with pencil on `mouseDown` event as mouse moves and stops on `mouseUp`. [Here](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/exbuild/paint/) is it running.

On the `mouseMove` event the example have functions

```
        context.line_to(event.offset_x() as f64, event.offset_y() as f64);
        context.stroke();
        context.begin_path(); //whats the use of this?
        context.move_to(event.offset_x() as f64, event.offset_y() as f64); //whats the use of this?
```

Why do we have the last two `begin_path` and `move_to` function call? `line_to` already draw a line from start to end and then from the end to next point as the mouse moves. Whats the use of `begin_path` and `move_to` ?

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn greet() -> Result<(), JsValue> {
    utils::set_panic_hook();

    let document = web_sys::window().unwrap().document().unwrap();
    let canvas = document
        .create_element("canvas")?
        .dyn_into::<web_sys::HtmlCanvasElement>()?;
    document.body().unwrap().append_child(&canvas)?;
    canvas.set_width(640);
    canvas.set_height(480);
    canvas.style().set_property("border", "solid")?;
    let context = canvas
        .get_context("2d")?
        .unwrap()
        .dyn_into::<web_sys::CanvasRenderingContext2d>()?;
    let context = Rc::new(context);
    let pressed = Rc::new(Cell::new(false));
    {
        let context = context.clone();
        let pressed = pressed.clone();
        let closure = Closure::wrap(Box::new(move |event: web_sys::MouseEvent| {
            context.begin_path();
            context.move_to(event.offset_x() as f64, event.offset_y() as f64);
            pressed.set(true);
        }) as Box<dyn FnMut(_)>);
        canvas.add_event_listener_with_callback("mousedown", closure.as_ref().unchecked_ref())?;
        closure.forget();
    }
    {
        let context = context.clone();
        let pressed = pressed.clone();
        let closure = Closure::wrap(Box::new(move |event: web_sys::MouseEvent| {
            if pressed.get() {
                context.line_to(event.offset_x() as f64, event.offset_y() as f64);
                context.stroke();
                context.begin_path();
                context.move_to(event.offset_x() as f64, event.offset_y() as f64);
            }
        }) as Box<dyn FnMut(_)>);
        canvas.add_event_listener_with_callback("mousemove", closure.as_ref().unchecked_ref())?;
        closure.forget();
    }
    {
        let context = context.clone();
        let pressed = pressed.clone();
        let closure = Closure::wrap(Box::new(move |event: web_sys::MouseEvent| {
            pressed.set(false);
            context.line_to(event.offset_x() as f64, event.offset_y() as f64);
            context.stroke();
        }) as Box<dyn FnMut(_)>);
        canvas.add_event_listener_with_callback("mouseup", closure.as_ref().unchecked_ref())?;
        closure.forget();
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's made in order to draw one line per mouse move.

Failing to call `beginPath()`, the context's subpath would still contain all the previous draw calls. So the next time `stroke()` is called, all these subpathes would be drawn, **again**, over the previous pixels, creating ugly artifacts.
The call to `moveTo` is then just to initialize the future small segment to the next mouse move vector.

Here is an example where the `strokeStyle` is changed every new mouse move. Since we don't call `beginPath()`, the whole path has its colored changed, and not just the last segment:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector( "canvas" );
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var hue = 0;

canvas.onmousemove = (evt) => {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  draw(evt.clientX - rect.left, evt.clientY - rect.top);
};

function draw(x, y) {
  ctx.lineTo( x, y );
  hue += 5;
  ctx.strokeStyle = `hsl(${hue}deg,100%,50%)`;
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

In comparison, here is what happens when calling `beginPath`:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector( "canvas" );
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var hue = 0;

canvas.onmousemove = (evt) => {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  draw(evt.clientX - rect.left, evt.clientY - rect.top);
};

function draw(x, y) {
  ctx.lineTo( x, y );
  hue += 5;
  ctx.strokeStyle = `hsl(${hue}deg,100%,50%)`;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo( x, y );
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

However, this may create issues at line junctions, since there is actually no joint.
A better approach is thus to store all the vectors in an Array, clear the whole context every frame, and redraw the full path: *(sorry, still in JS, my rust is <s>rusted</s> non existent)*.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector( "canvas" );
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const vectors = [];

canvas.onmousemove = (evt) => {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  draw(evt.clientX - rect.left, evt.clientY - rect.top);
};

function draw(x, y) {
  vectors.push( { x, y } );
  ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
  ctx.beginPath();
  vectors.forEach( ({x, y}) => ctx.lineTo( x, y ) );
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```